# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /home/u610435277/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/inc/jetpack.php on line 1

Tags: php

I designed one website using Wordpress on localhost and I uploaded it to online server using filezilla, everything went success but after upload, i am facing problem, error code is give below....

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /home/u610435277/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/inc/jetpack.php on line 1

[php error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZTYD.png)

I cross checked my php code several times, it is correct. my code

Please give me sufficient information

Comment: I would say there is an error ~ but without seeing the code it is all anyone can really say

Comment: Well if you ___Please give us sufficient information___ we will do our best. But this is not sufficient information

Comment: `Please give me sufficient information`.. You should give enough information first (the code for example)

Comment: Please provide sufficient information.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

May be you did not give a `<?php` at your file starting. That is why id did not expect function to begin there. Check it if this might be the problem.

Comment: Answers never start with **maybe**